# Swapping stage and prod tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to 'flip' staging tables to prod tables in SQL Server as part of an ETL process, but need to sort out some finer details on handling foreign keys.  The ETL process I am creating follows this pattern:

1. Truncate Stage table
2. Load Stage table with Prod data
3. Make inserts/updates in stage table
4. Swap the stage and prod tables

For example, i have 4 tables, 2 prod and 2 stage.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table_1]
( 
    [table_1_sk]         integer  NOT NULL ,
    [column_a]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_b]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_c]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([table_1_sk] ASC)
)
go
CREATE TABLE [Table_2]
( 
    [table_2_sk]         integer  NOT NULL ,
    [table_1_sk]         integer  NOT NULL ,
    [column_d]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_e]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_f]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([table_2_sk] ASC),
     FOREIGN KEY ([table_1_sk]) REFERENCES [Table_1]([table_1_sk])
)
go
CREATE TABLE [stage_Table_1]
( 
    [table_1_sk]         integer  NOT NULL ,
    [column_a]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_b]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_c]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([table_1_sk] ASC)
)
go
CREATE TABLE [stage_Table_2]
( 
    [table_2_sk]         integer  NOT NULL ,
    [table_1_sk]         integer  NULL ,
    [column_d]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_e]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    [column_f]           varchar(20)  NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED ([table_2_sk] ASC)
)
go
```

I started using sp_rename to simply rename the tables, but noticed that the foreign key was not sticking with the prod table.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Youll have to script out the sp_renames for the constraints as well (unless you're ok changing their naming convention).

Comment: Just curious, why don't you drop steps 1, 2, and 4 and make step 3 'Make updates/inserts in prod table"? That sounds much easier. Or keep your steps 1-3 and make step 4 "Run merge between stage and prod table"? Is this a one time change due to a big alter on the table or is this a recurring ETL process?

Comment: Please read this post before using sp_rename. https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/

Comment: dfundako, I am following this design pattern to shield the 'live' tables from any failures in the ETL process.  This is a reoccurring process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have to do this approach, I get everything ready as you described. Lets assume my live table is `myTable` and the table i plan to switch is called `myTable_New`. I would then:

1. Open an explicit transaction and error block
2. `sp_rename` myTable to myTable_Old
3. `sp_rename` myTable_New to myTable
4. Commit the transaction

At this point, the tables are switched, and the staging table has now replaced the live table. You can now go through at your leisure (i.e. outside the blocking period while you're renaming your live tables) and rename any constraints you want to fix the names of. So an additional:

5. Drop myTable_old OR `sp_rename` all the constraints on myTable_Old to suffix "_Old" as well (this way they won't conflict with the new table's constraints when you rename them)
6. `sp_rename` all the constraints on myTable_Old to remove the "_Old" suffix

Comment: After step 4, the constraint is now located on your myTable_New, and no longer on the live myTable, and steps 5 and 6 will simply rename the FK constraint, not re-point it.  Correct?

Comment: The constraints stay with the original objects. So if I have a table `myTable_Old` with constraint `myFK_Old`, when I `sp_rename` `myTable_Old` to be `myTable`, that table will still have the constraint `myFK_Old` on it. renaming the parent object doesn't detatch the constraints. But it also won't apply renaming to those constraints (which is why you have to do that separately).

Comment: That is what i am seeing, so I will need to drop/add constraints along with the sp_renames.  so it would look something like: sp_rename > commit > drop constraint > add constraint